# NSArray of NSDictionary - Simple Initialization syntax

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I'm beginning Objective-C (coming from Python)
I need to create and initialize a simple dictionary.
In Python I was used to do:

```py
arr = [
    {'fieldX': value1, 'fieldY': value2},
    {'fieldX': value3, 'fieldY': value3},
]
```

Here is what I'm doing in Objective-C

```c
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        value1, @"fieldX", value2, @"fieldY"
      , nil]
  , [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        value3, @"fieldX", value4, @"fieldY"
      , nil]
  , nil
];
```

Isn't there a simpler way to initialize this array of dictionaries ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

since ios6 you can use literals

```
NSArray *arr = @[
                 @{@"fieldX": value1, @"fieldY": value2},
                 @{@"fieldX": value3, @"fieldY": value3}
                ];
```

more info: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: I think we can even leave the leading comma, can't we ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY yes you can leave the leading comma